# Python line_profiler with object oriented code

Tags: python, profiling, line-profiler

I am trying to use the python [line_profiler by Robert Kern](https://pypi.org/project/line_profiler/) for some object oriented code and I am having trouble getting the desired output. My object is of the following form:

```py
class myObj:
    def __init__(self,inputs):
        #process inputs

    @profile
    def run(self):
        for t in range(self.timesteps):
            self.update()

    @profile
    def update(self):
        self.A += self.dA()
        self.B += self.dB()

    @profile
    def dA(self):
        #process data

    @profile
    def dB(self):
        #process data
```

I want to do line profiling for each of the methods with the `@profile` decorator, but when I run the profiler in an iPython environment using the command:

```py
test = myObj()
%lprun -f test.run test.run()
```

I get the following:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0 s
File: /Users/-----/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/line_profiler.py
Function: wrapper at line 111

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   111                                                   @functools.wraps(func)
   112                                                   def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
   113                                                       self.enable_by_count()
   114                                                       try:
   115                                                           result = func(*args, **kwds)
   116                                                       finally:
   117                                                           self.disable_by_count()
   118                                                       return result
```

I have tried it without the `@profile` decorators and it just tells me that all of the time is spent in the `update` method, which is pretty clear.